# Why does escodegen and esprima generate a parenthesis wrapper on my source code?

Tags: javascript, esprima, escodegen

I am using `escodegen` to add an ending code on my statement as below. In the leave method, I append a `.toArray()` call on the end of the statement.

```
const esprima = require('esprima');
const estraverse = require('estraverse');
const escodegen = require('escodegen');

const ast = esprima.parse('db.find()');
let finished = false;
estraverse.traverse(ast, {
  leave: (node, parent) => {
    if (node.type === esprima.Syntax.ExpressionStatement && !finished) {
      finished = true;
      let statement = escodegen.generate(node);
      statement = `${statement.substring(0, statement.lastIndexOf(';'))}.toArray()`;
      const findAst = esprima.parse(statement);
      node.arguments = findAst.body[0].expression.arguments;
      node.callee = findAst.body[0].expression.callee;
      node.type = findAst.body[0].expression.type;
    }
  },
});

const generated = escodegen.generate(ast);
console.log('generated  code:', generated);
```

The output from above code is: `generated  code: (db.find().toArray())`.
I don't understand why it wraps a parenthesis on my source code. Is there anything wrong in my source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating an incorrect AST. An `ExpressionStatement` has the form `{type: "ExpressionStatement", expression... }` .

You are modifying your `ExpressionStatement`, attaching to it `arguments` and `callee` and you are changing its `type` (to `CallExpression`). Here:

```
  node.arguments = findAst.body[0].expression.arguments;
  node.callee = findAst.body[0].expression.callee;
  node.type = findAst.body[0].expression.type;
```

Resulting a weird AST.

You can see it simply with : `console.log('generated  ast: %j', ast);`

A quick solution is attach mentioned parts where them belong (to `expression`). Resulting:

```
let finished = false;
estraverse.traverse(ast, {
    leave: (node, parent) => {
        if (node.type === esprima.Syntax.ExpressionStatement && !finished) {
        finished = true;
        let statement = escodegen.generate(node);
        statement = `${statement.substring(0, statement.lastIndexOf(';'))}.toArray()`;
        console.log(statement);
        const findAst = esprima.parse(statement);
        node.expression.arguments = findAst.body[0].expression.arguments;
        node.expression.callee = findAst.body[0].expression.callee;
        node.expression.type = findAst.body[0].expression.type;
        }
    },
});
```

It will generate a correct AST, that will output the expected `db.find().toArray();`. 
But I think the code is a bit complicated and does too much work, it parses `db.find()` then it generates code and parses it again.

Additionally you can return `this.break()` in `leave` to stop the traverse.

In my humble opinion it would be much clear:

```
var new_expr = {
        type: "CallExpression",
        callee: {
            type: "MemberExpression",
            computed: false,
            object: null,
            property: {
                type: "Identifier",
                name: "toArray"
            }
        },
        arguments: []
    };

const ast3 = esprima.parse('db.find()');
estraverse.traverse(ast3, {
    leave: function(node, parent) {
        if (node.type === esprima.Syntax.ExpressionStatement) {
            new_expr.callee.object = node.expression;
            node.expression = new_expr;
            return this.break();      
        }
    },
});
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Another question is: does `this.break()` stop the whole process or it only stops the current statement? There are many other codes in the process need to be executed. I wonder whether they get skipped if I put `this.break()`  statement there.

Comment: Oh, I think it terminates the traversal, if you want to do more things in the same traversal you should not use it.